# Get match in fixed string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following fixed string.

```
edbe801bf92fe7b770f72df2d722df0a
```

I need to get the `2df2d` part after the fourth `7` and before the last `7`

I tried matching with

```
[a-z0-9]*7[a-z0-9]*77[a-z0-9]*7(.*)
```

But its getting the wrong part of the string

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your pattern will match if you add another `7` after your capturing group.

```
.... (.*)7
```

But for readability and to save you a headache, I would simplify this.

```
(?:[^7]*7){4}([^7]*)
```

I used a non-capturing group here `?:` to group the expression for multiple matches, but not to save it as a matched/captured portion of the string.

Regular expression explanation:

```
(?:        group, but do not capture (4 times):
 [^7]*     any character except: '7' (0 or more times)
   7       match '7'
){4}       end of grouping
(          group and capture to \1:
 [^7]*     any character except: '7' (0 or more times)
)          end of \1
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/rB2oN0)